# How to set weights_column in H2OAutoML?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, h2o

I was trying use [H2OAutoML](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html) in Python to create a regression model, but I can't find how to pass 'weights_column'.

I try this two ways:

```
# Create the AutoML model.
aml = H2OAutoML(
        seed=0,
        max_runtime_secs = None,
        include_algos=['GBM', 'DRF'],
        stopping_metric='RMSE',
        exploitation_ratio=0.1,
        weights_column='weight'
    )
```

This code raise an `TypeError`:
`TypeError: H2OAutoML got an unexpected keyword argument 'weights_column'`

```
# Create the AutoML model.
aml = H2OAutoML(
        seed=0,
        max_runtime_secs = None,
        include_algos=['GBM', 'DRF'],
        stopping_metric='RMSE',
        exploitation_ratio=0.1,
        algo_parameters={'weights_column': 'weight'}
    )
```

And this code raise `H2oResponseError` on train step:

```
H2OResponseError: Server error water.exceptions.H2OIllegalValueException:
Error: Illegal value for field: algo_parameters: weights_column
```

Can Someone help me to use this parameter? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the `weights_column` from the `.train()` method. For example:

```
aml.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train, weights_column='weight')
```

Comment: A way to remember which args go in which method (the `H2OAutoML()` method or the `.train()` method) is that all algo-related args go in the former and all data-related args (e.g. `weights_column`) go in the latter.